# javascript function in a for loop not causing crashing browser

Tags: javascript

I'm new at coding and am trying to figure out why this doesn't work. the function works fine I'm assuming there is a fundamental flaw in the sumArray function that is not processing

```
// SET UP FUNCTIONS FOR LATER USE   

// sumArray - takes all values within an array and adds them 
var sumArray = function(x){
    var sum = 0;
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
        sum += parseInt(x[i]);
    };
    return sum;     
};

// create an array and use sumArray function inside of a loop.

// This works
var arrayTest = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
document.write (sumArray(arrayTest);

// This crashes the browser
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
document.write("<br/>" + sumArray(arrayTest) + "<br/>"); 
};
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: You should `[1, 2, 3 ...]` instead of `new Array(1, 2, 3 ... )`

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis in document.write(sumArray...

Comment: The term "crash the browser" means that the entire browser process fails.  Is that what's happening?

Comment: And you should accept both answers, which will crash not only your browser, but will cause the whole universe collapse. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare "i" with `var`:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
```

in both loops. If you don't do that, there's just one global "i" clobbered by both loops.

Comment: It won't "crash the browser" in this case but it will make thinks work incorrectly.

Comment: Well, nothing should "crash the browser" short of browser bug.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it would only cause the main loop to run only once, but certainly needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Just before the second loop, you're missing a `)`.

```
document.write (sumArray(arrayTest) ); // <-- right here
```

---

Additionally, be very careful with `document.write`. If it runs *while* the document is loading, you'll probably be alright. Be sure you don't use it after the doc has loaded.